# How to iterate json data in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

How to iterate the json data in jquery.

```
[{"id":"856","name":"India"},
 {"id":"1035","name":"Chennai"},
 {"id":"1048","name":"Delhi"},
 {"id":"1113","name":"Lucknow"},
 {"id":"1114","name":"Bangalore"},
 {"id":"1115","name":"Ahmedabad"},
 {"id":"1116","name":"Cochin"},
 {"id":"1117","name":"London"},
 {"id":"1118","name":"New York"},
 {"id":"1119","name":"California"}
]
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
  //use obj.id and obj.name here, for example:
  alert(obj.name);
});
```

Comment: What if I do not know the names of key and values from the JSON object?

Comment: what is `i` and `obj` in the arguments list?

Comment: @Adamnick I would hazard a guess that `i` is the index and `obj` is the object that makes up each element.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use regular javascript too, which I think would be a bit faster (though I'm not really sure how jQuery optimizes `each`):

```
var data = [{"id":"856","name":"India"},
 {"id":"1035","name":"Chennai"},
 {"id":"1048","name":"Delhi"},
 {"id":"1113","name":"Lucknow"},
 {"id":"1114","name":"Bangalore"},
 {"id":"1115","name":"Ahmedabad"},
 {"id":"1116","name":"Cochin"},
 {"id":"1117","name":"London"},
 {"id":"1118","name":"New York"},
 {"id":"1119","name":"California"}
];

var data_length = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < data_length; i++) {
  alert(data[i]["id"] + " " + data[i]["name"]);
}
```

**edited** to reflect Nick's suggestion about performance

Comment: It depends, accessing `.length` isn't trivial, so best to cache it if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$(yourjsondata).each(function(index, element) {
    alert('id: ' + element.id + ', name: ' + element.name);
});
```

Comment: `.each()` is intended for operating on jQuery objects, which aren't meant to contain ordinary arrays, better to use `$.each()` as it was intended.

Comment: @Nick, I thought that jquery objects such as ones returned from jquery selectors were ordinary arrays. I agree with you that in this case the static `$.each` method would be more appropriate.

Comment: they have a bunch of other properties as well, you can use `.get()` (which internally is `.toArray()`) to get a base array of DOM elements though.

Comment: @Nick, yes I know that objects in this array are *enhanced* with additional properties and methods.

Comment: Perhaps a minor difference, but I think it would be more accurate to say that a jQuery object is an object enhanced with some properties from Array. Otherwise it implies that they have the full functionality of an Array.

Answer (score 3):

iterate on all the object's properties with the $.each function. in each iteration you'll get the name/key and the value of the property:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  alert(key+ " *** " + val);
});
```