# Iterate JSON Response in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Am new to jquery. Have json response from php in this format.

```
{
"div1":{"data":"minute=0,hour=27,day=649,month=19K,smallSize=0, id=XXXXXXXXXX, ip=yyyyyyyyyyy<br \/>\nminute=0,hour=34,day=825,month=24K,smallSize=0, id=XXXXXXXXXX, ip=yyyyyyyyyyy<br \/>\nminute=0,hour=40,day=980,month=29K,smallSize=0, id=XXXXXXXXXX, ip=yyyyyyyyyyy<br \/>\n","address":"232323"},
"div2":{"data":"","address":"232323"},
"div3":{"data":"minute=0,hour=28,day=682,month=20K,smallSize=0, id=XXXXXXXXXX, ip=yyyyyyyyyyy<br \/>\nminute=0,hour=36,day=866,month=26K,smallSize=0, id=XXXXXXXXXX, ip=yyyyyyyyyyy<br \/>\nminute=0,hour=42,day=1019,month=30K,smallSize=0, id=XXXXXXXXXX, ip=yyyyyyyyyyy<br \/>\n","address":"232323"}
}
```

How i need to iterate this JSON in jquery and fetch the div1>data and div1>address,div2>data and div2>address. can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate json data in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233354/how-to-iterate-json-data-in-jquery)

Comment: Do you use `$.getJSON` to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** jQuery version of the same here **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/5EhaK/2/)**

```
function viewJSON (jsonObj) {
   var divData;
   $.each (jsonObj, function (key, value) {
     divData = value; //gives me the value of div 1

     $. each (value, function (key, value) {
         console.log ('Key is ' + key + ' Value is ' + value);
     });

   });   
}
```

you can also use simple javascript iterate to get div1>data, (non-jQuery version)

```
   function viewJSON (jsonObj) {
   var divData;
   for (divKey in jsonObj) {
     divData = jsonObj [divKey]; //gives me the value of div 1

       for (dataKey in divData) {
         console.log ('Key is ' + dataKey + ' Value is ' + divData[dataKey]);
       }

     }    
   }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/5EhaK/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this using jQuery `each` method.

```
var obj = {  ... };

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    //key - each object in the json object
    //value - its value
});
```

If it is a well formed json string and not an object then you need to first parse it using `parseJSON` method and then use it to iterate through it.

```
   var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Then you can directly access the required properties as below

div1>data  => `obj.div1.data;`

div1>address => `obj.div1.address;`

div2>data => `obj.div2.data;`

div2>address => `bj.div2.address;`

Answer (score 0):

Loop or directly access?

```
$.each(json, function(key, val) {
    console.log(key + ' ' + val.data + ' ' + val.address);
});
```

Direct access:

```
console.log(json.div1.data);
console.log(json.div1.address);
// etc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/CKDXU/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply parse the JSON and talk directly to the resulting object.

```
var theResponse = ...;
var obj = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
console.log(obj.div1.data);
console.log(obj.div1.address);
```