# parse json response in jquery Laravel 5.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have read other questions but my problem is little different. I am getting the response in a format like this from an eloquent query in Laravel.

```
[{"id":1,"message":"sdfsdf","message_for":1,"message_by":2},{"id":2,"message":"hello","message_for":4,"message_by":2},{"id":4,"message":"hi how are you?","message_for":1,"message_by":2}]
```

There is no variable attached to each object like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714494/iterate-json-response-in-jquery) `div1` , `div2` etc. 
This is my `ajax` code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/chat',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: sessionStorage.getItem('user_id') },
        //cache: false,
        success:function(data){
            /*var x;
            for(x in data){
                /!*$("span.messages").fadeIn("slow").append(data[x]);
                $("span.messages").append("<br>");*!/

            }*/
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('data is :'+data.id);
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

And this is my controller function from where I am returning the response.

```
public function getUserMessages(Request $request){

        $id = (int)$request->request->get('id');
        $messages = Message::where('message_by' , $id)->get()->toJson();

        return $messages;
    }
```

I tried using `data["message"]` but it does not work. Using `data[0]` will return `[`.

Comment: You need to json_encode : `return Response::json($message);`

Comment: actual problem is how to loop through>

Comment: Please show what returns `data` by editing your post

Comment: data is returned by $messages as i described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `foreach` to get the data

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
  alert(obj.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using data[0] will return [

That seems like `data` is a String, not an Object.

One solution is to modify your PHP code so it tells the browser it is sending JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Another solution is to explicitly parse the JSON to get the object.

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

Additionally, you have an array.  The conventional way to iterate through an array is to increment an index.  The newer way is to use the built-in [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.  Alternatively, use jQuery's `$.each()` as another answer suggested.

```
success:function(response){
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        var x;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1)
            {
            var record = data[i];
            $("span.messages").fadeIn("slow").append(record.message);
            $("span.messages").append("<br>");
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a collection of object from the controller. so you can do like this.

```
   success:function(data){    
        var x;
        for(x in data){
            $("span.messages").fadeIn("slow").append(data[x]['message']);
            $("span.messages").append("<br>");

        }

  },
```

the x will be your index.. based from your return.. you can call

```
data[x]['id']
data[x]['message']
data[x]['message_for']
data[x]['message_by']
```

depending what you need