# How can I get member names from an object?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting JavaScript object key list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list)
>   [How to iterate json data in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233354/how-to-iterate-json-data-in-jquery)

I have a json like this one:

```
var myJSONObject = {
                    "flowers": [
                        {"id":"1","name":"Red Flower","url":"flower_1.png"},
                        {"id":"2","name":"Purple Flower","url":"flower_2.png"},
                        {"id":"3","name":"Yellow Flower","url":"flower_3.png"},
                        {"id":"4","name":"Violet Flower","url":"flower_4.png"},
                        {"id":"5","name":"Purple Flower","url":"flower_5.png"}
                    ],
                    "bouquet": [
                        {"first":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},
                        {"second":[1,2,3,4,5,6]},
                        {"third":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
                    ]
            };
```

Now my questin is how can I pull only the names of members of "bouquet"...into array.
Something that will look like that :  ["first","second","third"]?

Comment: This is not related to JSON, which is a data exchange format, but simply to JavaScript objects.

Comment: @FelixKling and John, this question is distinct from the others. In case you didn't notice: The named keys are unknown. A double loop is required to solve this.

Comment: @Rob W: don't think so: `for (var p in myJSONObject.bouquet) ...`

Comment: @RobW: I see what you mean. Still, I'd assume (I'm an optimist) that one knows how to iterate over an array.

Comment: @justsomebody Your suggestion returns a list of `[object Object]`s, while the OP wants `["first",...]`. These "duplicates" are dealing with lists of the kind `[a, b, c]`, while this question is about `[{a:..}, {b:..}, {c:..}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent Firefox browsers, the following can be used (so-called [Array-comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_comprehensions)):

```
var list = [Object.keys(i)[0] for each (i in myJSONObject.bouquet)];
```

If `Object.keys` is supported, use:

```
var list = [];                        // Create list
for (var i=0; i<myJSONObject.bouquet.length; i++) {
    var keys = Object.keys(myJSONObject.bouquet[i]); //List keys
    list.push(keys[0]);               // Store first named key
}
```

In other browsers, you can use:

```
var list = [];                        // Create list
for (var i=0; i<myJSONObject.bouquet.length; i++) {
    var key = myJSONObject.bouquet[i];
    for (var j in key) {              // Get the first named key
        list.push(j);                 // Store named key
        break;                        // <--- First named key, so break loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an es:harmony version of array comprehensions

Comment: [Array comprehensions](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:array_comprehensions) are listed at the [proposals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals) page.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i< myJSONObject["bouquet"].length; i++)
{
  var o = myJSONObject["bouquet"][i];
  document.write(Object.keys(o) + "<br>");
}
```

> output: first second third

[JSFiddle for confirmation](http://jsfiddle.net/NibblyPig/wH7Cg/)

Comment: Already found the answer...but thank you all!

Comment: @BorisD Beware of the code in this answer. `Object.keys` returns an array. If you're going to create a list in a similar way as the answer, you will get an array like: `[['First'],['Second'],['Third']]`. This does matter if you want to directly perform string operations (such as `charAt`) on the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in an environment that supports modern ECMA additions, you can use `Object.keys` (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) or you can polyfill your own if you need to, something like this:

```
function getKeys(obj) {
    var ret = [], prop;

    for (prop in obj) {
        if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
            ret.push( prop );
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

Usage:

```
var keys = getKeys({ foo: "a", bar: "b" }); // -> ['foo', 'bar']
```

hope that helps! cheers.