# iterate json element received from php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some info in JSON which is coming from `PHP` via `Ajax`

**`{"5":"rahul","26":"karan","28":"jatin"}`**

I wants to get key separate which are **5,26,28**
and separate name which are `rahul,karan,jatin`
I use this code in `java script`.  But doesn't get result as i want.

```
for (var key in ajaxresponse) {
    if (ajaxresponse.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
        alert(key + " -> " + JSON.stringify(ajaxresponse[key]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use 2 arrays, to get to what you want:

```
var keys = [], vals = [], key,
ajaxresponse = JSON.parse(ajaxresponse);//parse JSON, which is quite important, too!
for (key in ajaxresponse)
{
    if (ajaxresponse.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        keys.push(key);
        vals.push(ajaxresponse[key]);
        console.log(key + '->' + ajaxresponse[key]);//no need to call JSON.stringify on a string
    }
}
console.log(keys.join(', '));//will list all keys, comma-separated
console.log(vals.join(', '));//ditto for values
```

Comment: Result from your solution

 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 

{, ", 5, ", :, ", r, a, h, u, l, ", ,, ", 2, 6, ", :, ", k, a, r, a, n, ", ,, ", 2, 8, ", :, ", j, a, t, i, n, k, k, ", } 

But i need 5,26,28 only and rahul,karan,jatin

Comment: You've forgotten to parse the JSON, it would seem: `ajaxresponse = JSON.parse(ajaxresponse);` should precede this code

Answer (score 5):

On a really simple level, the `for()` is using `ajaxresponse` and the if/alert are using `response`.

If the code you've pasted the actual code? If so, that could be your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

follow this post to iterate your json data with the help of jQuery

[iterate using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233354/how-to-iterate-json-data-in-jquery)