# Unable to parse JSON string returned from Server Side method in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to parse this json data

```
[
    {   "title":"Yorkshire 199/8 * v Durham 237/10", 
        "link":"http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/693421.html?CMP=OTC-RSS", 
        "description":"Yorkshire 199/8 * v Durham 237/10", 
        "guid":"http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/693421.html"},
    {
        "title":"Essex v Warwickshire 271/7 *", 
        "link":"http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/693423.html?CMP=OTC-RSS", 
        "description":"Essex v Warwickshire 271/7 *", 
        "guid":"http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/693423.html"},
    {
        "title":"Singapore v Malaysia", 
        "link":"http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/774365.html?CMP=OTC-RSS", 
        "description":"Singapore v Malaysia", 
        "guid":"http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/774365.html"}
]
```

returning from server side method and using this method to iterate through each item

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Default.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
               //data: JSON.stringify({ 'p': 'Sent Text' }),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               async: true,
               cache: false,
               success: function (data) {
                   //alert(data.d) //returns the result set displayed above.
                   $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                       alert(obj.title); // returns undefined.

                   });
               },
               error: function (x, e) { alert(x.responseText); }
           })
```

but it always return undefined.
Is there any issue with my jquery function or with data? My server side function is working fine and the above Jquery function also show the returned values but I am unable to parse this value.

I also tried this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233354/how-to-iterate-json-data-in-jquery) to fix this issue but nothing succeeds.
Any one please...

Comment: `console.log(data);` Is it what you expect?

Comment: I need to display all three items on my webpage. That is why I want to get obj.title, obj.description and so on...

Comment: @liaqatali That's fine. What does `console.log(data)` show you?

Comment: Is the output to the console for `console.log(data);` what you expect when you inspect the variable `data`!? If it is, what is `console.log(obj);`? Debug!

Comment: @eascarello! @JasonP
it returns "Invalid App Id: Must be a number or a numeric string representing the application id"

Comment: So `data` is not what you've posted above. Solve that and see where that gets you.

Comment: @JasonP! The above result in my question is taken by alert(data.d);

Comment: Then that's what you need to iterate: `$.each(data.d, ...`

Comment: @JasonP, with respect, I tried this too. alert(obj.title) again alerts 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the wrong object:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Default.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
           //data: JSON.stringify({ 'p': 'Sent Text' }),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           async: true,
           cache: false,
           success: function (data) {
               //alert(data.d) //returns the result set displayed above.
               $.each(data.d, function (i, obj) { // <---- use data.d here, not data
                   alert(obj.title);

               });
           },
           error: function (x, e) { alert(x.responseText); }
       })
```

When you just iterate over `data`, `obj` takes the values of each property of data. So, for example, at some point, `obj` is `data.d`. You then try to alert `obj.title`, which is `data.d.title` and doesn't exist.

By iterating over `data.d`, you set `obj` to be, for example, `data.d[0]`. Then,

```
obj.title === data.d[0].title
          === "Yorkshire 199/8 * v Durham 237/10"`
```